# Tab icon should only be displayed when it is selected

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

I'm working on tablayout and I have created a drawable i.e. show logo for selected tabitem only and hide for rest. Since, drawable isn't loosing the dimension and @android:color/transparent still taking space which makes tablayout messy in terms of UX.

below is my drawable code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/selected_tab_icon" />
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" android:state_selected="false" />
</selector>
```

Is there is any way by which I can hide those unselected tabs vacant spaces of transparent drawable?

Comment: Not just through the drawables setup, it seems. The default `ImageView` that the icon goes into has an exact width and height set, so it won't collapse on its own. You'll need something else, like possibly a custom tab `View`.

Comment: If a custom `View` solution is acceptable, it turns out that we can do it relatively simply: https://drive.google.com/file/d/11DhxDQxWgNnubO7NHr8rR8oATshNnnvn/view?usp=sharing. That's the same `ImageView` and `TextView` setup as in the default tabs. Unfortunately it won't work out of box with `setupWithViewPager()` and similar functionalities, but that's just how it is for any custom tab `View`.